# Java. Log4j2 in Netbeans does not print the right output, nor does it save the file

Tags: java, log4j2

After having read numerous posts, I am trying to add Log4j2 to my project but to no avail.

First, I created an XML configuration file and added it to my Project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN">
  <appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
       <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="MyFile" fileName="config/LogFile.log">
       <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>             
 </appenders>

 <loggers>     
    <root level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="Console" level="debug"/>
      <appender-ref ref="Console" level="info"/>
      <appender-ref ref="MyFile" level="error"/>
    </root>    
 </loggers>
</configuration>
```

[image]

[image]

Then, I used it in my Main class:

```
public class Main 
{
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> 
        {
            LOGGER.debug("Debug Message Logged !!!");
            LOGGER.info("Info Message Logged !!!");
            LOGGER.error("Error Message Logged !!!");

            Main main = new Main();
            main.startApplication();
        });
    }
}
```

However, I believe that my configuration file is not properly loaded. I receive the following message in my Console, which does not correspond to the pattern written in the xml file:

```
run:
INFO  Main: Info Message Logged !!!
ERROR Main: Error Message Logged !!!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 20 seconds)
```

And the log file is not saved in my Application/config/ folder.

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't make screenshots of text/source/logoutput, ever!

Comment: Sorry. Corrected.

Comment: Maybe try removing the `src/` part from the path to the configuration file?

Comment: Nope. Already tried that. Same outcome.

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn I have only used log4j1.x and your XML content looks like it is for 1.x. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Tried some of the XML examples from the site. And still the same result. Thanks, anyways!